# The Martian Monetary System

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Is the following Proof Correct ? **I am required to construct the proof using Strong Induction**

**Theorem**. The Martian monetary system uses colored beads instead of coins. A blue
bead is worth $3$ Martian credits, and a red bead is worth $7$ Martian credits. Then for all $n\ge 12$, there is some combination of blue and red beads that is worth $n$ credits.

**Proof.** For the case $n\in\{12,13,14\}$ the following combinations 
$$\begin{cases}
12 = 3\cdot4 +7\cdot 0\\ 
13 = 3\cdot6 +7\cdot 1\\  
14 = 3\cdot0 +7\cdot 2\\
\end{cases}$$ 
are sufficient. Now assume for an arbitrary $n\in\{15,16,17,...\}$ that for all $k\in\{12,13,14,...,n-1\}$ there exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $k = 3\cdot a+7\cdot b$. Evidently $n = (n-3)+3$ since $n\ge 15$ it  follows that $m = n-3\ge 12$ consequently using inductive hypothesis we have integers $x$ and $y$ such that $m  = 3\cdot x+7\cdot y$ thus $n = m+3 = 3\cdot (x+1)+7\cdot y$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You have a typo in the title of your question. That is not usually a good idea.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct and generally well explained. The only thing it needs is punctuation. Several times, the sentence stopped making sense, forcing me to back up to figure out where you began a new phrase. My suggestion is: add commas after $n \in \{...\}$, $k \in \{...\}$, $n\ge 15$ and "inductive hypothesis". End the sentence after $n = (n-3)+3$, after $m = n - 3 \ge 12, and after $m = 3\cdot x + 7\cdot y$.